# (Inner) Join with if then statement

Tags: mysql, delphi, join

I have 2 tables, one master (`Table1`) one detailed (`Table2`), with one filed in common (`Id`).
I use this query in order to get all records with the same id for a specific date

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 LG_TESTA 
INNER JOIN Table2 LG_RIGHE ON (Table1.ID=TABLE2.ID) 
WHERE TABLE1.DATE='2016/11/28'
```

In `Table2` I have these fields too `Price1, Price2, Price3, Quanity.`

How can I do in order to get a calculated field in according to the above query?
something like

```
((Price1 + price2 + price3) * Quantity) as Total
```

Comment: You should add a `calculated field` to the table

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `calculated field` like the follow :

1- Add a `calculated field` to your table.

2- on `Evenements` , search for `OnCalcFields` .

3- Write your code :

```
YOURTABLETotal.Value:=((TABLE2Price1.Value + TABLE2price2.Value +
TABLE2price3.Value) * TABLE2Quantity.Value);
```

**Note:** Make sure that the type of your `calculated field` is `Float`.

**OR**

```
SELECT *,((Price1 + price2 + price3) * Quantity) As Total FROM Table1 LG_TESTA 
INNER JOIN Table2 LG_RIGHE ON (Table1.ID=TABLE2.ID) 
WHERE TABLE1.DATE='2016/11/28'
```

Comment: I'd use `ftCurrency` if the `TField` is representing money

Comment: Yes , if , Also you can check `Currency` Property.

Comment: i already tried the query as above, but the fields Price1, Price2, and Price3 are stored in The second table (Table2).